# Why am I not getting a vertical scrollbar as the content overflows the wrapping div?

Tags: html, css

I want a simple design where I have a menu on the left side and a main content div on the right side.

Everything works so far except that the vertical scroll bar in my main content div is not showing up. This is how I am doing it:

```
<html>
<body style="overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">

    <table style="height:100%; width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="height:100%; width:200px; background-color:#DDAAAA;">
                Menu
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="position:fixed; top:0px;height:100%; width:100%; background-color:#88AA88; overflow:auto;">
                    CONTENT ...
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

What I want is that the main content resizes as the browser window gets resized - but this should not affect the actual content displayed in that div.

**Edit:**

Trying it without the table:

```
<html>
<body style="overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">

    <div style="height:100%; width:100%; background-color:#DDDDDD;">

        <div style="height:100%; width:200px; background-color:#DDAAAA; float:left; overflow: hidden;">
            Menu
        </div>

        <div style="margin-left:200px;height:100%; width:100%; background-color:#88AA88; ; overflow: auto;">
            CONTENT
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the downvote for?

Comment: i don't know why someone downvotes this. seems like a valid question. basically your problem is, that you use `width:100%`, the width will be the same as the entire page!!!. there is actually a scrollbar, but you cant see it because its outside the viewport. also position:fixed doesnt make any sense here. i also don't know how to fix this with a table. because td has `display:table-cell` it will be as big as its content. you will either have to give the div a fixed size (not percentage) or not use a table

Comment: The `height:100%` won't work unless ALL the parents of your `table` has the same `height:100%' including `body`and `html` (or any other fixed height). Btw. Year 2015. Try not to use tables as layouts. You will always be happier :)

Comment: @x4rf41 Thanks for the hint. But how would I handle a window resize event in that case? Would I use JavaScript for that and resize the height/width on every resize event?

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez I am using GWT. So I'm just trying to build the overall structure of the content. I won't be necessary to write more than 20-30 lines of HTML :)